# Add Item to List<KeyValuePair<Object, List<Object>>>

Tags: c#, .net, list, keyvaluepair

I'm creating the following List with a KeyValuePair which contains an object and another List:

```
var testList = new List<KeyValuePair<classTypeObject, List<DataTypeObject>>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<classTypeObject, List<DataTypeObject>>(classTypeObject.Mountain, new List<DataTypeObject>()),
    new KeyValuePair<classTypeObject, List<DataTypeObject>>(classTypeObject.City, new List<DataTypeObject>()),
};
```

How can I add items to the List for example to the second entry with the Key=classTypeObject.City?

Comment: you could address it by index  `testList[1]`, unless you are looking for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be:

```
testList[1].Value.Add(....)
```

Value = List
Key = classTypeObject

If your key is a little bit more complex, you could
use lambda expressions:

```
testList.Where(x => x.Key == classTypeObject.City).First().Value.Add(...)
```

Comment: Sorry, not to see the wood for the trees. Thank You

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.